# Is there any way to add selected font-weight and create a variable font file?

Tags: fonts, variable-fonts

Is there any way to add selected font-weight and create a variable font file.
I need only regular, semibold and bold to reduce file size.
i used [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/) for size compression but output was not correct.
Or else any other method to combine 3 woff2 font files into single file.
There is an online tool for checking website score [Yellowlabs](https://yellowlab.tools/) and when we check website score there must be only one font file.